# How do i use a for loop to do this output?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in java and I need help with this code. I have to let the user enter a word and the output as follows,(I used Canada as an example)

Canada

anada

nada

ada

da

a

However, I'm not sure what to do. This is what I have so far

```
import java.util.*;
public class javapdf2413_17 {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter in a single word");
        String wordEntered = in.next();

        for (int i = wordEntered.length(); i>=0; i--) {
            System.out.println(wordEntered.substring (0, i));
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordEntered.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(wordEntered.substring(i));
}
```

The above `substring` method takes the beginning index of the string and returns a substring from that index (inclusive) till the end of the string.

Comment: Why does this work?

Answer (score 0):

You're close. `String.substring(1)` will return everything from the second character to the end. And I would use that in a loop with test against the empty string. Like,

```
while (!wordEntered.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(wordEntered);
    wordEntered = wordEntered.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: [Help vampire](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49592498/522444)